# how can i read output from console in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to read output from .exe file of a c++ program and trying to use this output for further use in my asp.net web application but it isn't working
this is what i have done so far

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process MyProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    MyProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Hussain\\Documents";
    MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "demo.exe";
    MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "MyArgument";
    MyProcess.Start();
    String s = MyProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new 
         System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Hussain\\Documents\\123.txt");
    file.WriteLine(s);

    file.Close();
    MyProcess.WaitForExit();
    MyProcess.Close();
```

Comment: Rather than writing the output of the first program into a file and reading from said file in the second program, can you simply have program1 write to stdout and program2 read from stdin, then use a pipe to connect the output, as in `PROG1 | PROG2` on the command line?

Comment: thanks for your reply Bob
when i typed this code the console appears upon clicking a button in my web application with the output of the program
System.Diagnostics.Process MyProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        MyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        MyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        //MyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        MyProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Hussain\\Documents";
        MyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "demo.exe";
        MyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "MyArgument";
        MyProcess.Start();

Comment: @Bob
how can i save this output or assign it to some textBox?